# Google App Engine - Java - Special characters get altered when reading post-request

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, utf-8, character-encoding

My Google App Engine-servlet handles post-request. 
It tries to fetch a XML-string but special characters get altered.
Swedish characters like å/ä/ö are transformed into something like: Ã¥

```
public String getXML(HttpServletRequest req){
    String XML = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader b = req.getReader();
        StringBuffer xmlBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while((XML = b.readLine()) != null) {  
               xmlBuffer.append(XML);  
        }
        XML = xmlBuffer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //maybe later
    }
    return XML;
}
```

The post-data is always a XML-string of UTF-8 that will be used to verify a hash.

Edited question: 2013-12-05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find (google) the answer .. finally.

```
req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
public String getXML(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException{    
    String input = null;
    if ((input = (String) req.getAttribute("com.xp.input")) == null) {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();

        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        input = buffer.toString();
        req.setAttribute("com.xp.input", input);
    }
    if (input == null) {
        return "";
    } 
    String header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
    String body = input.substring(38, input.lastIndexOf('>')+1);
    body = body.substring(body.indexOf('<'));
    return header+"\n"+body+"\n";

}
```

This worked for me, I just found the code of another post, and added some Character Encoding.

Answer (score 0):

In this construct

```
new String(XML.getBytes(),"UTF-8")
```

you're doing a reinterpretation of the string's bytes from [platform's default charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) to `UTF-8`.

Try just reading the request without any explicit conversion, like this:

```
public String getXML(HttpServletRequest req){
    try {
        BufferedReader b = req.getReader();
        StringBuffer xmlBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String XML;
        while((XML = b.readLine()) != null) {  
               xmlBuffer.append(XML);  
        }
        return xmlBuffer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

or using [Apache IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html):

```
public String getXML(HttpServletRequest req) {
    try {
        return IOUtils.toString(req.getReader());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

`getReader()` is responsible for doing any nessesary character conversion, as [stated in the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader%28%29)

> The reader translates the character data according to the character encoding used on the body

Comment: @rzymek: Just a note: the conversion bytes-to-characters still happens, but this time the reader takes request encoding into account: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader()

Comment: @Niklas - ryzemek's code is correct. How are you checking the chars? Note that admin console does not properly show UTF-8 chars.

Comment: @PeterKnego I've check the `getReader()` docs before posting to make sure there's none of that dreadful "platform's default charset", but you're right - I've edited the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @PeterKnego I check data by saving Strings to MemCache. I've tried it and it now handles special characters.